# Estimating the number of tokens in a pile

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, point-estimation

We have a pile of tokens numbered from $1$ to $n$, where $n$ is unknown. $k$ tokens are drawn from the pile  at random without replacement(i.e. the numbers that we get from tokens are unique). Say the number written on the tokens are $a_1,\  \dots, a_k$ what is the best estimation for $n$ that you can give.

I remember our teacher said that if the tokens were drawn with replacement, then the MLE estimation of $n$ would be $\max_i a_i$. But in the other case(drawn without replacement), the number must be reported larger than the maximum with respect to $k$(i.e. for smaller $k$-s we would report $c\max$ rather than $\max$ where $c$ shrinks as $k$ grows). But now that I check MLE for this case (i.e. the $n$ that maximizes $\frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}$) is also $\max_i a_i$. Am I doing it wrong? Or can someone give a mathematical way of explaining the constant $c$ which where $c\max$ is reported?(The intuition is fine)

Comment: (+1) Although it's clear you desire an analysis of the MLE, please note that "best" can mean various things, depending on what it costs you to be wrong in your estimate.  In practical applications (especially with small $k$) the MLE is probably not a good choice for this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Comment: Thank you @Kodiologist, how should I close the problem?

Comment: @Sakura You mean close the question? You can't close your own question, but you can delete it. There should be a "delete" link at the bottom of your post.